# Docker compose is not copying any files

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

Quite simple: the docker-compose configuration below does not allow any files to persist after running. So when I do `docker exec -i -t aas-job-hunter_web_1 ls /app -alt`, I see nothing.

Here is the (non-)working minimal example: https://github.com/philastrophist/test-docker

I'm on Windows 10, I've allowed mounted drives and enabled the TLS connection. I'm not sure what else to do. The thing that most confuses me is that `requirements.txt` is clearly copied over (since it installs it all) but it isn't there when I have a look `docker exec`.

My directory structure is:

```
parent/
    website/
        manage.py
        ...
    Dockerfile
    docker-compose.yml
    ...
```

## Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6

#WORKDIR /app

# By copying over requirements first, we make sure that Docker will cache
# our installed requirements rather than reinstall them on every build
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

# Now copy in our code, and run it
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 8000
CMD python website/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
# CMD tail -f /dev/null # use when testing
```

## docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
     - .:/app
    links:
     - db

  db:
    image: "postgres:9.6"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: hunter2
```

## Traceback:

```
> docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --build
Building web
Step 1/6 : FROM python:3.6
 ---> 0668df180a32
Step 2/6 : COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3073d0bef876
Step 3/6 : RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8ad63bbb3de5
Step 4/6 : COPY . /app
 ---> 16390cdd6c2c
Step 5/6 : EXPOSE 8000
 ---> Running in f628000e8961
Removing intermediate container f628000e8961
 ---> 80e6994cfbd2
Step 6/6 : CMD python website/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
 ---> Running in acb6b25eb558
Removing intermediate container acb6b25eb558
 ---> da8876d78103
Successfully built da8876d78103
Successfully tagged aas-job-hunter_web:latest
Starting aas-job-hunter_db_1 ... done
Recreating aas-job-hunter_web_1 ... done
Attaching to aas-job-hunter_db_1, aas-job-hunter_web_1
db_1   | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-05-24 21:23:31 UTC
db_1   | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1   | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
web_1  | python: can't open file 'website/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
aas-job-hunter_web_1 exited with code 2
```

Comment: Do you have a `.dockerignore` in the same directory as your compose and Dockerfile?

Comment: No .dockerignore

Answer (score 1):

Actually it copies files.

1. Solution 1

Change CMD to :

```
CMD python /app/website/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

2. Solution 2

You call WORKDIR before the `/app` folder is created. So change your Dockerfile to :

```
FROM python:3.6.2

# By copying over requirements first, we make sure that Docker will cache
# our installed requirements rather than reinstall them on every build
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

# Now copy in our code, and run it
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
#EXPOSE 8000
CMD python ./website/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
# CMD tail -f /dev/null # use when testing
```

And call it after.

Moreover remember that in your current `docker-compose` file you are using bind mounts, not volumes, so the context - `.` will **replace entirely** the content of `/app` in your container.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is nothing wrong with `COPY`. But, you need to set the work directory to `/app` as your `manage.py` file is inside `/app/website`, not in `/website` inside Docker.

So, I think your `Dockerfile` should be like this:

```
FROM python:3.6

RUN mkdir /app

COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8000
CMD python website/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment `#WORKDIR /app`.
I also cleaned the other parts a bit up to utilize the `WORKDIR` more.

```
FROM python:3.6
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8000
CMD python website/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: ```Building web
Step 1/7 : FROM python:3.6
 ---> 0668df180a32
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 91165ba8058b
Step 3/7 : COPY requirements.txt .
 ---> b944561033cc
Step 4/7 : RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 4a5cbc06f32a
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/requirements.txt'
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r /requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1```

Comment: without the `/` in front of `requirements.txt` it installs correctly.I still get the same error at the end though

Comment: Missed the /.
Are you in the `parent` directory when building? You could debug further with `docker-compose run web bash` or `docker-compose run web ls`

Comment: @SuperSandro2000 I'm in the parent directory when building. And I've done what you recommend - I still find no files whatsoever in the /app directory (or indeed any directory)